# Initializing Vector4f with Vector3f

Tags: c++, vector, type-conversion, eigen, data-conversion

I am trying to perform view transform to a 3D point in world coordinates stored in Vector3f, my view matrix is stored in Matrix4f. Would it be possible to initialize Vector4f with an extended Vector3f. This's what I've done so far:

```
Eigen::Vector4f Graphics::getLookVectorView() {

Eigen::Matrix4f viewMatrix = dxToEigen(m_camera->getViewMatrix());
Eigen::Vector3f Vec = m_eyeball0->getLookVector();
Eigen::Vector4f lookVec4;
lookVec4 << Vec.x(), Vec.y(), Vec.z(), 1;
return (viewMatrix*lookVec4);
//Eigen::Vector3f lookVecEye1 = m_eyeball1->getLookVector();}
```

but I get an error when I try to do it this way, is there any way where I can extend Vector3f by one and store in Vector4f to perform the transform?

This's the error I get:

```
1>....\eigen-eigen-b30b87236a1b\eigen\src\core\assign.h(499): error C2338: YOU_MIXED_MATRICES_OF_DIFFERENT_SIZES
1>....\eigen-eigen-b30b87236a1b\eigen\src\core\plainobjectbase.h(414): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'Derived &Eigen::DenseBase<Derived>::lazyAssign<Eigen::Matrix<float,4,1,0,4,1>>(const Eigen::DenseBase<Eigen::Matrix<float,4,1,0,4,1>> &)' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            Derived=Eigen::Matrix<float,3,1,0,3,1>
1>        ]
```

Any help is highly appreciated :)

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/8n7bsaTqW Looks like it's compiling fine here and the way you've written it looks like it'd be the correct way to do it. Any other code that might be the cause of the error?

Comment: What come after the with?

Comment: Thank you so much all! I called the function to be stored in Vector3f that's where the error was... :/

Comment: I usually do this:`Eigen::Vector4f lookVec4(Vec(0),Vec(1),Vec(2),1)` .

Comment: You may want to take a look at `homogeneous` and `hnormalized` if you actually need to do this manually (http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__Geometry__Module.html#gaf3229c2d3669e983075ab91f7f480cb1). Otherwise, use `Affine3f` as suggested by @LGrementieri.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could circumvent the conversion using [Affine3f](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-3.2/group__Geometry__Module.html#title9) instead of Matrix4f.
An Affine3f object internally stores a Matrix4f (that can be accessed by `Affine3f.matrix()`) and the multiplication with a `Vector3f` returns a `Vector3f` performing the same calculation done using a `Vector4f` created adding the trailing 1.

```
#include <Eigen/Geometry>


Eigen::Vector3f Graphics::getLookVectorView() {
    Eigen::Matrix4f viewMatrix = dxToEigen(m_camera->getViewMatrix());
    Eigen::Affine3d affine(viewMatrix);
    Eigen::Vector3f Vec = m_eyeball0->getLookVector();
    return (affine*Vec);
}
```